# Adding menu to CefSharp winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am using Winforms menustrip now but it overlays on browser content.
Is there any possibility to add menu to CefSharp Winforms which does not overlap with the browser content.

Code Used Earlier:

```
ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("[url]"); 
Form.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
```

Fix for the issue:

```
ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("[url]");   
toolStripContainer1.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
```

Comment: Look at the CefSharp Minimumexample for a working version

Comment: Thank you.As per the example adding a toolstripcontainer for the browser worked

Comment: Try adding the browser to a panel instead of on the WinForm surface. Post your code on how initalize the webbrower.

Comment: Yeah,that was the mistake which i did.Using ToolStriipContainer of winforms to hold the browser solved it.